# how can data be coloured when using multiple labels in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

When using the multiple labels, how to select the color of a sample according the first label or the second label??

like data :A:a :A:b :A:c which all have 2 labels

I want to use different color, however they are coloured by A all is the same.

I have tried the :a:A :b:A :c:A but it doesn't function..

I am really confused about it

Comment: Do you have an example that you can point to, e.g. using gist.neo4j.org?

Comment: I am sorry I can't make sense about what you said...Anyway, I found a way to solve the problem although seems stupid.. I add a '_' to the common label. like _A and the neo4j will color according to the other label, ignoring _A. So I can according my second label, like a, b, c to color the point. Anyway, thank you all the same~~~